# How to use Volumes in Docker-Compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have two different containers [Node.js; Python(Where I run a flask API to generate samples by running a  deep learning model)]. The Node.js is a Web app where the samples generated in Python are shown. Here is the problem, I know each container has his own filesystem, the communication between containers works well, but the samples generated are in the Python container, and I cannot show them in the web app, because the filesystem is another one. I'm trying to create a volume and make a filesystem for the two containers,  unsuccessfully.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  nvsmi:
    image: nvidia/cuda:11.0-base
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - capabilities:
              - gpu
  web:
    build: ./synt/web/app
    volumes: 
      - type: volume
        source: volume-data
        target: /var/lib/docker/volumes/volume-data/_data/web/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

  tensorflow:
    build: ./synt/python_ws
    volumes: 
      - type: volume
        source: volume-data
        target: /var/lib/docker/volumes/volume-data/_data/python_ws
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - nvsmi
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - capabilities:
              - gpu

volumes:
  volume-data: 
   external: true
```

node.js Dockerfile, similar to Python:

```
FROM node:12

# app directory


COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install 

COPY . .


EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

*The image that runs python is called tensorflow*

Locally this aproach works well, the files directory used is below.

```
-docker-compose
 -Synt -> main folder
  -python_ws
   -Dockerfile
   -[all scripts needed to run the api]
  -web
   -app
    -Dockerfile
    -[html, controllers, routs,...]
```

To underline the idea, I'm able to run docker-compose and everything works, all the communication between containers,... The problem is that I cannot print data (Audio) in the Node.js, where this data is created in python container. Any guess for what I'm doing wrong in the volumes?

Comment: The `target:` says where in the container the volume should be mounted; the application probably isn't finding the data directory at that path.  (You shouldn't usually directly refer to or access `/var/lib/docker` content in any case.)

Comment: @DavidMaze , should i do something like: Target: /python_ws ?

Comment: Use whatever directory inside the container the application expects to write its data to.  This should be a different directory from where the application is: you don't want to accidentally overwrite the application code itself with volume content.